# Javascript not removing or adding classes

Tags: javascript, html

I am creating a chat website for fun, and I am trying to use `.classList.add();` and `classList.remove();` to switch between screens without having to export and use subdomains. I have tried messing with the syntax and tried using `.setAttribute();` and `.removeAttribute();`. I am trying to learn how to use JavaScript, so if the answer is super simple, it is very probable that I missed it. An explanation on why my code didn't work would also be useful, but don't spend a ton of time on it. Thanks for any help!
Edit: After fixing an issue with my code to make it work, which was changing a `==` to a `===`, I found out that it was the socket code that was making it not work, so I will add my server.js code and hope that it might make the question a little more clear.

### JavaScript:

code.js

```
// commented code is in the original script, but I changed it so that it can be run without downloads
(function(){
  const app = document.querySelector(".app");
  const socket = io();

  let uname;

  app.querySelector(".join-screen  #join-user").addEventListener("click", function(){
    let username = app.querySelector(".join-screen #username").value;
    if(username.length == 0) {
      return;
    }
    socket.emit("newuser", username);
    uname = username;
    app.querySelector(".join-screen").classList.remove("active");
    app.querySelector(".chat-screen").classList.add("active");
  });
})();
```

Server.js

```js
const express = require("express");
const path = require("path");

const io = require("socket.io")

const server = require("http").createServer(app)
const app = express();

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname+"/public")));


io.on("connection", function(socket){
  socket.on("newuser", function(username){
    socket.broadcast.emit("update", username + " has joined the conversation");
  });
  socket.on("exituser", function(username){
    socket.broadcast.emit("update", username + " has left the conversation");
  });
  socket.on("chat", function(message){
    socket.broadcast.emit("chat", message);
  });
});

server.listen(5000);
```

### HTML:

In the CSS, I have it set so that the div without the "active" class will not show.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Website</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="app">
      <div class="screen join-screen active">
        <div class="form">
          <h2>Join Chatroom</h2>
          <div class="form-input">
            <label>Username</label>
            <input type="text" id="username">
          </div>
          <div class="form-input">
            <button id="join-user">Join</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="screen chat-screen">
        <div class="header">
          <div class="logo">Chatroom</div>
          <button id="exit-chat">Exit</button>
        </div>
        <div class="messages"></div>
        <div class="typebox">
          <input type="text" id="message-input">
          <button id="send-message">Send</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="code.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Well... if you `username` is length 0 you will not reach the part of this function that removes or adds classes. Are you sure you have a username set? Also make sure that your `.join-screen`  and  `.chat-screen`  elements are children of  `.app`. Otherwise replace `app.querySelector`  with `document.querySelector`

Comment: Maybe you should also post your HTML markup, without it we can only guess the issue

Comment: Ok, I'll get that right now.

Comment: I made a fiddle for the code, what was the problem that you are having? The only thing that I added was CSS to hide the divs. I didn't even need to change == to === https://jsfiddle.net/9k6xhedv/

Comment: @imvain2 I already have CSS code for that, sorry if I didn't make that clear.